# clear color of picture

Tags: c#, image, math, image-processing, bitmap

i have a picture with background=white and contain 3 object(circle,rectangle,triangle ) with different color:

[image]

i get color of each pixel by:

```
   Bitmap myBitmap1 = new Bitmap("4111.bmp");

       Color c,c2;          
        for (int Xcount = 0; Xcount < myBitmap1.Width; Xcount++)
        {
            for (int Ycount = 0; Ycount < myBitmap1.Height; Ycount++)
            {
                c = myBitmap1.GetPixel(Xcount, Ycount);
         
                listBox1.Items.Add("R=" + c.R + "/" + "G=" + c.G + "/" + "B=" + c.B);
            }
        }
```

now How can I change the color of the rectangle and triangle to give white.

Indeed,How do I clear the rectangle and triangle ;

Given that we do not know the color of the rectangle and triangle

Comment: You first have to find those shapes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126192/shape-recognition-algorithms

Comment: i try to clear rectangle and triangle of any picture

Comment: @MaEb The problem here is that you do not know what constitutes a triangle or rectangle. The aforge library is a way of identifying shapes. After you identify the shapes you can act upon them.

Comment: @MaEb Shai asks have you already wrote any code that didn't worked to clear shapes? if so show the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this with in the `for loop` :-

```
if (myBitmap1.GetPixel(Xcount, Ycount) == Color.Red)
{
    myBitmap1.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, Color.Blue);
}
```

Comment: Am I color blind or I don't see red color in picture? :)

Comment: this is a gray picture.that do not know color of